# JQuery html() does not work with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an application, and I need to parse JSON and display it. I used the `getJSON()` function, which is working fine, and I'm using `$(class_name).html(text)`. When I view the isolated HTML file in the browser, minus the CSS formatting, I can see the text, but when I run the application, and navigate to the page, the text (with the CSS formatting) does not show up. Even when I Inspect the element, the text is not present in it. Why is this happening?

Thank you

What `console.log(data);` contains:

```
schools:"Schools"
search-school:"Search school by number or name"
student-det:"Student Details"
students:"Students"
summary:"Summary"
```

The actual JSON:

```
{
"schools":"Schools",
"search-school":"Search school by number or name",
"student-det":"Student Details",
"students":"Students",
"summary":"Summary"
}
```

```js
$.getJSON("./lang/en.json", function(data) {
  $(".SecondTopBarTitleProperties").html(data.schools);
});
```

```css
.SecondTopBarProperties
{
 background-color:#333333;
 height:40px;
}
.SecondTopBarTitleProperties
{
 color:white;
 font-size:16px;
 margin-top:6px;
 margin-left:6px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container SecondTopBarProperties">
  <label class="SecondTopBarTitleProperties"></label>
  <button data-bind="click:NewSchool" type="button" class=" pull-right btn btn-primary btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Add School</button>
</div>
```

Before the "Add School" button, it's supposed to display "Schools".

Plain HTML: [image: Plain HTML]

Formatted: [image: Formatted]

Any help please?

Comment: Can't help if we can't see your code

Comment: _Why is this happening?_ because you have something wrong in your code. can you show up that one?

Comment: you need to be more specific and show some code or reproduce the problem

Comment: Ah sorry, ignore the spaces; I've edited them now. They're not in my code.

Comment: You need to include sample JSON, and whatever CSS you are using

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait with the execution of your JS until the DOM is ready, else your JS can't manipulate the DOM elements, because they do not yet exist.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    // Code inside this block will be executed when the DOM is ready
    var data = {
      schools: "Schools"
    };
    $(".SecondTopBarTitleProperties").html(data.schools);
}); // DOM ready
</script>
<div class="container SecondTopBarProperties">
  <label class="SecondTopBarTitleProperties">

  </label>
  <button data-bind="click:NewSchool" type="button" class=" pull-right btn btn-primary btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Add School</button>

</div>
```

If this does not work for you, then you need to check what your `$.getJSON("./lang / en.json ", function(data) {` does, because we can't test this part for you.

Maybe it's due to copy&paste, but it should probably read `$.getJSON("./lang/en.json", function(data) {` without those spaces.

Check your browser's `Network` tab (in the browser's console) to see what you're requesting from the server and what the server returns.

Comment: I tried this, it's not working. My `$.getJSON()` function works fine, because its purpose is to retrieve the corresponding JSON string, which it does properly.

Comment: Can you provide the content of `data` that's returned from `getJSON()` in your question? please provide it from a console.log() and don't just post the file's content.

Comment: Sure, I've added it

Comment: Well, I'm all out of ideas. Your JSON looks fine. If you use a `data`  variable (like I did) instead of `getJSON`, does it work?

Comment: Yep, I inserted it like you did, and it still doesn't work. Like I said, when I load just the HTML file, I can see the text "Schools". It's only when I load the whole application with all the formatting that it disappears.

I've added screenshots too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your styles into your html code i prepared this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/4/

```
$(function(){

var data = { name = "hey" }

$('.SecondTopBarTitleProperties').html('<span   style="color:red">'+data.name+'</span>')
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in w3schools and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = { name :"hey" };
  alert('hi');
  $('.SecondTopBarTitleProperties').html(data.name);
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="container SecondTopBarProperties">
 <label class="SecondTopBarTitleProperties"></label>
 <button data-bind="click:NewSchool" type="button" class=" pull-right btn btn-primary btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Add School</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```